# Search values in a concatenated column based on a list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I am wondering if there is a way to search values from a list in a concatenated column without un-concatenate the column.

Look at the following table as an example:

| ID | Aleatory Stuff |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | banana, rice, potato |
| 2 | cucumber, breakfast |
| 3 | Heaven, Bucket, test |
| 4 | Ball, Pan, Candy, shirt |
| 5 | draw, cellphone, bubble |

I'd like to create another column based on a list, as follows:

```
list_0 = ["Ball", "cellphone", "breakfast", "rice", "test"]
```

new_df:

| ID | List Stuff |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | rice |
| 2 | breakfast |
| 3 | test |
| 4 | Ball |
| 5 | cellphone |

Is there any possibility?

Comment: What have you tried so far? For example, do you know how to use regex and the `.str` accessor? Or for another approach, do you know how to use `.apply()`? Please read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I tried to un-concatenate, @wjandrea. However this is not the best option in my case. Thank you for the reading tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. You can split the string column `Aleatory stuff` using `str.split(", ")` where `", "` is the separator between words in your case. Once the items are splited, you can use `set.intersection(set)` to find the common items between each row and your list.

You can check my code with an example similar to yours:

```
import pandas as pd 

test_data = [
    {"id": 1, "aleatory_stuff": "banana, rice, potato"},
    {"id": 2, "aleatory_stuff": "cucumber, breakfast"}
]

test_list = ["rice", "cucumber"]

test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_data)
test_df["list_stuff"] = test_df["aleatory_stuff"].str.split(", ").apply(lambda x: list(set(x).intersection(set(test_list)))[0])

print(test_df)
```

```
   id        aleatory_stuff list_stuff
0   1  banana, rice, potato       rice
1   2   cucumber, breakfast   cucumber
```

Answer (score 1):

with [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and a *listcomp* :

```
df["List Stuff"] = [x for l in df.pop("Aleatory Stuff").str.split(", ")
                    for x in l if x in list_0]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   ID List Stuff
0   1       rice
1   2  breakfast
2   3       test
3   4       Ball
4   5  cellphone
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) with aggregation:

```
import re

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, list_0))
# 'Ball|cellphone|breakfast|rice|test'

df['List Stuff'] = (df['Aleatory Stuff'].str.extractall(f'({pattern})')
                    [0].groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
                   )
```

*NB. if you want a case insensitive match add `flags=re.I` as parameter to `extractall`.*

Output:

```
   ID           Aleatory Stuff List Stuff
0   1     banana, rice, potato       rice
1   2      cucumber, breakfast  breakfast
2   3     Heaven, Bucket, test       test
3   4  Ball, Pan, Candy, shirt       Ball
4   5  draw, cellphone, bubble  cellphone
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `str.findall` to find all occurrences of matching regex pattern

```
pat = r'(?i)\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(list_0)
df['List Stuff'] = df['Aleatory Stuff'].str.findall(pat).str.join(',')
```

---

```
   ID           Aleatory Stuff List Stuff
0   1     banana, rice, potato       rice
1   2      cucumber, breakfast  breakfast
2   3     Heaven, Bucket, test       test
3   4  Ball, Pan, Candy, shirt       Ball
4   5  draw, cellphone, bubble  cellphone
```

PS: The regex flag `(?i)` is used for case insensitive match